# Calender tooltip using Javascript and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this question has been asked several times.But i didn't get any proper solution.My requirement is to show html tooltip in my calender. So after searching so many times in google.I found one solution from this 
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/craga89/N78hs/).

```
// Setup FullCalendar
(function() {
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

var tooltip = $('<div/>').qtip({
    id: 'fullcalendar',
    prerender: true,
    content: {
        text: ' ',
        title: {
            button: true
        }
    },
    position: {
        my: 'bottom center',
        at: 'top center',
        target: 'mouse',
        viewport: $('#fullcalendar'),
        adjust: {
            mouse: false,
            scroll: false
        }
    },
    show: false,
    hide: false,
    style: 'qtip-light'
}).qtip('api');

$('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: true,
    height: 300,
    header: {
        left: 'title',
        center: '',
        right: 'today prev,next'
    },
    eventClick: function(data, event, view) {
        var content = '<h3>'+data.title+'</h3>' + 
            '<p><b>Start:</b> '+data.start+'<br />' + 
            (data.end && '<p><b>End:</b> '+data.end+'</p>' || '');

        tooltip.set({
            'content.text': content
        })
        .reposition(event).show(event);
    },
    dayClick: function() { tooltip.hide() },
    eventResizeStart: function() { tooltip.hide() },
    eventDragStart: function() { tooltip.hide() },
    viewDisplay: function() { tooltip.hide() },
    events: [
        {
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, 1)
        },
        {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
            end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
            allDay: false
        },
        {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
            allDay: false
        },
        {
            title: 'Birthday Party',
            start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
            end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
            allDay: false
        }
    ]
});
}());
```

But the problem is it is showing "qtip is not a function" when i am deploying my code in the server.Another thing is this example using fullcalender.min.js version 1.6.0,but mine is  fullcalender.js version 2.4.1.I need to implement same type tooltip as given in example in mycalender.

Comment: Have you loaded the JS requirements of the qtip plugin?

Comment: Yes... but still facing problem